# Error on groovy script (Admin Shell) for Teiid

Tags: groovy, teiid

I have this teiid.groovy script to execute an SQL query on a Teiid VDB:

```
sql=connect(${jdbc:teiid:PREVIEW_d3cd3bd1-7b0a-4ca0-94f9-84e37ce7b106_iCare_P5_project.1@mm://localhost:31000}, {$user1}, ${user2014!});  
sql.execute("select * from ( exec "iCare_P5_Resident_Model"."iCare_P5_Resident_Proc"() ) AS X_X");  
sql.close();
```

When I execute it using

```
./adminshell.sh . /path/to/file/teiid.groovy
```

I get this error;

```
FATAL: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
groovysh_parse: 2: expecting '}', found 'b0a' @ line 2, column 44.
{jdbc:teiid:PREVIEW_d3cd3bd1-7b0a-4ca0-9
                             ^

1 error

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
groovysh_parse: 2: expecting '}', found 'b0a' @ line 2, column 44.
{jdbc:teiid:PREVIEW_d3cd3bd1-7b0a-4ca0-9
                             ^
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using double quotes for your string, and its contents. Simply change the line to:

```
sql.execute('select * from ( exec "iCare_P5_Resident_Model"."iCare_P5_Resident_Proc"() ) AS X_X')
```

Also, the first line isn't groovy. Maybe try

```
sql = connect('jdbc:teiid:PREVIEW_d3cd3bd1-7b0a-4ca0-94f9-84e37ce7b106_iCare_P5_project.1@mm://localhost:31000', 'user1', 'user2014')
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the reply. However, the error is within connect() not execute(). I have tried your suggestion either way and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the answer, you had errors on 66% of your script ;-)